# Remove /post/ from url Magneto 2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, post

I am using **Magento ver. 2.3.4**

**How to Remove Post form URL.**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try this RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/module-home/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183238/htaccess-remove-string-from-url

Comment: check this link --- https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-blog/issues/195

Comment: @PushpendraSingh can you plz tell where is changes.

Comment: @DineshThakur, you need to add this code in your htaccess file

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/module-home/?(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]  only this

Comment: module-home change with post and try

Comment: module-home change with post and try